# Can't add TableRow to TableLayout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

```
TableLayout mTableLayout;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mTableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
mTableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.addView(imageView);
mTableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

I want to add an imageview to a table row, then add this table row to Table Layout.
But when this run, the screen has nothing happen. And I don't know why.
I try to find Logcat and break point but nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok the issue here is you are creating row first the the table layout; try adding row to layout first then view to row like below reference code:

   TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
   TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("This is text");

   tl.addView(row);
   row.addView(tv);
```

Comment: sorry.I try to do like what you say but nothing change.

Comment: then try it through xml

Comment: Sorry. I can't do this in XML. The purpose of this that I want to add many imageView to 1 row and then add the row to Table Layout by code. So I can't do that thing in XML.

Comment: Use grid layout instead